# Recommended way to handle callbacks in libraries

Tags: function, callback, erlang

I am writing a small parsing library and I would like to let users pass a callback function to process items as they get parsed instead of waiting for the end of the input.

My current (naive) solution is something like:

```erlang
parse(Input, Callback) ->
  parse(Input, <<>>, Callback).

parse(<<>>, Item, Callback) ->
  Callback(Item);

parse(<<$\n, Rest/binary>>, Item, Callback) ->
  Callback(Item),
  parse(Rest, <<>>, Callback);

parse(<<C/utf8, Rest/binary>>, Item, Callback) ->
  .parse(Rest, <<Item/binary, C/utf8>>, Callback).
```

Which is then called in the application/module this way:

```erlang
my_lib:parse(Input, fun do_something/1).
```

From my understanding of the [efficiency guide](https://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/functions.html#function-calls), this shouldn't be much slower than local calls since:

> Calling or applying a fun (Fun(), apply(Fun, [])) is just a little slower than external calls.

When looking at code from some OTP behaviors or applications, passing a Module, Function and Arguments seems to be preferred. Is there any particular reason for that?

Unfortunately, I don't have enough experience to form an option on the usability side of the question and I would like to know the following:

From a usability point of view what is currently the preferred method for libraries to allow users to pass callback functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about performance/efficiency, but for usability/maintainability it might be better for you to define your own behaviour, like…

```erlang
-module parser.
-export [parse/2].

-callback parse_item(binary()) -> term().

-spec parse(binary(), module()) -> term().
parse(Input, CallbackModule) ->
  parse(Input, <<>>, CallbackModule).

parse(<<>>, Item, CallbackModule) ->
  CallbackModule:parse_item(Item);

…
```

Comment: That's a pretty nice idea. Didn't think about it. I do have a hard time seeing how to make it play nicely with other behaviours like say a gen_server. How can I let my callback function update my gen_server state? Right now the only solution I can see is calling gen_server:cast or call in my callback and update the state in handle_cast but it kind of ruins the whole idea.

Comment: So I tested this and followed the idea of OTP behavior callbacks by letting the user pass a Term as a second parameter of the initial parser call. This Term is carried around and passed to the callback function the same way that it is done for the State or StateData of the gen_server and gen_statem. At the end of the parsing this Term is returned. It is pretty neat and way more flexible than funs. I will definitely go with this solution.